# About Ovewriting variables in scanf()

Tags: c, loops, caching, while-loop, scanf

I am creating a test program that shows an error message when an entered number is less than, or equal to, ten:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void errorMessage()
{
   printf("\n This number is less than, or equal to, 10. Please try again. ");
}

int main()
{
   int a;
   printf("\n Enter a number that is greater than 10. ");
   while(scanf(" %d",&a) <= 10)
   {
      errorMessage();
      printf("\n Enter a number that is greater than 10. ");
   }
   printf("\n This number is greater than 10.");
   return 0;
}
```

The problem comes when a number less than, or equal to, ten (*e.g.* 5) is entered, then a number greater than ten (*e.g.* 15) is entered afterwards. The program executes `errorMessage()` even if the number makes the `while` statement false. I figured out that `scanf()` somehow stores the input value of `int a`. I wanna know how one would clear the input of `int a` before the program runs the `while` loop again.

Comment: Note:  `" "` in format serves no purpose here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf()` does not return the *scanned* value, it returns the number of inputs matched and stored successfully.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.4 (*emphasis mine*)

> *The `scanf` function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before
>   the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, **the `scanf` function returns the
>   number of input items assigned,** which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in
>   the event of an early matching failure.*

You need to compare the value stored in `a`, which is passed as the argument of teh conversion specifier `%d` to `scanf()`.

You'll need two steps:

- Check for the return value of `scanf()` to ensure there is no scanning failure.
- Check for the stored value in the supplied argument for the input range, as you wish.

A modified version of the code may look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

void errorMessageAndCleanup()
{
   printf("Enter a valid number!!\n");
   while (getchar() != '\n');            //cleanup the existing buffer with invalid input
}

int main(void)
{
   int a;
   printf("Enter a number that is greater than 10. \n");
   while(  ! ((scanf(" %d",&a) == 1) && (a > 10)) ) // check for scan success AND 
   {                                                // the scanned value IF success
      errorMessageAndCleanup();
      printf("Enter a number that is greater than 10.\n");
   }
   printf("This number is greater than 10.\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sourav Gosh' answer explains what you do wrong. A solution could be:

```
while(scanf(" %d",&a)!=1 || a<= 10)
```

This first checks `scanf` was able to read and convert a number, and then checks if that number is less than or equal to 10.

Comment: Note:  If input is non-numeric  (`scanf(" %d",&a)` returned 0), a test like this without consuming the non-numeric text leads to an infinite loop.